# How to navigate to a nested screen of nested stack navigator of bottom tab navigator using commonActions.reset

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

I am trying to navigate to a nested screen from a different tab.

My navigator looks like

```
AppContainer: StackNavigator
  TabBar: BottomTabNavigator
       tab1: Screen             
       tab2: Screen            
       tab3: stackNavigator   
           screenList: screen (initial screen)       
           screenDetails: screen (detail screen)  
  OtherScreen1:
  OtherScreen2:
```

How can I go to screenDetails (under tab3), from any other tab or screen?

I am using commonActions. If I set routes like below, then it is navigating to screenList (which is the initial screen of tab3 stack navigator)

```
navigationRef.dispatch(
    CommonActions.reset({
       index: 1,
       routes: [
         { name: 'TabBar', params: { screen: 'tab3' } },
         { name: 'TabBar', params: { screen: 'tab3', params: { screen: 'screenDetailes, params: { detailId: '123 } }}
       ],
     })
)
```

But if I set routes like the one below, goBack() does not take the screen to screenList instead navigates to the tab1.

```
navigationRef.dispatch(
     CommonActions.reset({
           index: 0,
           routes: [
             { name: 'TabBar', params: { screen: 'tab3', params: { screen: 'screenDetails, params: { detailId: '123 } }}
           ],
      })
)
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to stack and bottom both navigation?

Comment: Yes, the Bottom tab bar should be visible both in screenList and screenDetails screen.

Comment: may be this my code help you to understand https://snack.expo.dev/@gattu/navigationcontainer-%7C-react-navigation

Answer (score 1):

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
    import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
    
    const Stack1 = createStackNavigator();
    const Stack2 = createStackNavigator();
    
    function Screen1() {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Nested')}>
          <Text>Go to nested screen</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
    
    function NestedScreen() {
      return (
        <Text>This is the nested screen</Text>
      );
    }
    
    function Screen2() {
      return (
        <Text>This is screen 2</Text>
      );
    }
    
    function App() {
      const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
      
      return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Tab1" component={Stack1Screen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Tab2" component={Stack2Screen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      );
    }
    
    function Stack1Screen() {
      return (
        <Stack1.Navigator>
          <Stack1.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
          <Stack1.Screen name="Nested" component={NestedScreen} />
        </Stack1.Navigator>
      );
    }
    
    function Stack2Screen() {
      return (
        <Stack2.Navigator>
          <Stack2.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
        </Stack2.Navigator>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;



<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Nested')}>
  <Text>Go to nested screen</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```